# How to span a background color across the whole line instead of just under the text when writing on a picture?

Tags: html, css

I am writing on a picture and need help with spanning the background color across the line instead of just the text. I tried setting its width to 100%, max-width to 1024px (its the max-width of the whole page) and also tried setting display to inline-block. it still is under the text only. Here's the code:

```css
.mc {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  position: relative;
}


/*main container (for text on image)*/

.cntrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  font: 1.5em Calibri, Arial;
  text-align: center;
}


/*centered text on image*/

.bgclr {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


/*span bgclr over the whole line*/
```

```html
<div class="mc">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg" alt="Error loading picture!" width="100%">
  <div class="cntrd"><span class="bgclr">
    A place to visit when you need help with softwares and 
    operating systems.</span></div>
</div>
```

I think its because of centering the text on image. I even tried `!important` property on text's `max-width` and `display` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
.mc {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  position: relative;


}


/*main container (for text on image)*/

.cntrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  /*left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  color: black;
  font: 1.5em Calibri, Arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
}


/*centered text on image*/

.bgclr {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


/*span bgclr over the whole line*/
```

```html
<div class="mc">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg" alt="Error loading picture!" width="100%">
  <div class="cntrd"><span class="bgclr">
    A place to visit when you need help with softwares and 
    operating systems.</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay ,thankyou very much for your response.  A couple questions: 1) It works partially (Idk how to insert a screenshot here so I'll try the google photos way - https://photos.app.goo.gl/pYzKFUgMeQBjiTtz5). 2) What does that transform: translate(-50%, -50%); actually do?

Comment: for `transform` you can learn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) basically it moves element first number is horizontally, second vertically. I will update my answer for your desired result shortly

Comment: Did you try my answer in `Full page`?

Comment: Um, assuming by full page (since its highlighted by stackoverflow as a code), you mean on my desktop with a resolution of 1024x768. Yes, the attached screenshot is of that resolution.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/kJg57puXrNuHrRUA6 Lot better. I was thinking (in between all this) that I could just edit an image to add some text on it because I want to learn backend. This is a project website I am creating just to get started with backend.

Comment: Well, can't find an 'accept' button in here. I am currently not eligible for upvoting (11/15 points) but I have had my response recorded (the moment you answered), so it will get voted sometime in future. Thanks.